# what is the safe way to pass parameter in web api in angular 8

Tags: angular

can any one help me what is the safe way to transmit paramaeter  in web api in angular 8. so that our parameter value can not be seen by any one in browser Network tab in firefox or any othwr browser

Comment: Encryption. The network tab will capture everything as it's the purpose of it. Your only chance is to encrypt from javascript, but I doubt this will add any extra security. Care to share why and what you are trying?

Comment: i have encrypted the value and decripting it but problem is thatwhat we have encripted in angular typesscript file can nit be decripted in asp.net web api . pramameter value can be change while trinsmiting in api by clicking on web api and selecting editandsend and by changing header and send again .then response gets changed . so not able to handle these .